# is 90c normal for i7-9750H in laptop

Tags: laptop, gaming, intel-core-i7, cpu-temperature

is 90c normal for [i7-9750H](https://superuser.com/search?q=i7-9750H) when playing games in laptop and 85c for GTX 1660 TI

Comment: That seems very hot to me. What do the manufacturer's specifications say about allowed temperature ratings.

Comment: It's not *normal*, but is within running parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Most CPUs these days have procHot (T-junction temperature) around 100, so it's hot, yes, but not dangerously so.

Better cooling would help, though difficult to achieve on laptops.

Intel Ark says 100° for that CPU - https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/191045/intel-core-i7-9750h-processor-12m-cache-up-to-4-50-ghz.html

Comment: So i don't need to worry about that?

Comment: No. It's within tolerance.